# Snap container width to width of number of visible thumbnails?

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

See my site here: http://www.element17.com.  It may be desirable to change to a different album than the default in order to have more thumbnails available.  The *Paris* album has the most images in it.

If you click the "Show Photo Grid" button in the very bottom-right, you'll see the photo/thumbnail grid I've contrived.

Right now it scales with the viewport, and I'd like it to continue to do so, but instead of smoothly increasing in size with the viewport I'd like it to only be as wide as the number of thumbnails that currently fit in the viewport, so that there's no empty whitespace to the right of the number of displayed thumbnails.  I'd like it to remain 20px from the right of the viewport with any empty space being displayed on the left.

How can this be accomplished?

The current code follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid_outer">
  <div id="grid_inner">
    <div class="grid_thumb button">
      <span class="thumb_title">TITLE</span>
      <img class="thumb_image" src="image.jpg" alt="TITLE">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_thumb button">
      <span class="thumb_title">TITLE2</span>
      <img class="thumb_image" src="image2.jpg" alt="TITLE2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid_outer {display:none; position:absolute; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75); right:20px; left:20px; bottom:60px; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px; border-radius:20px; max-height:480px; overflow:hidden;}
.grid_thumb {position:relative; float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0; width:150px; height:150px;}
.thumb_image {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border-radius:5px;}
.thumb_title {position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; z-index:100; padding:8px; background:#000; border-radius:0 5px 0 5px;}
.button {cursor:pointer;}
```

So I've discovered that if I set the width of `#grid_outer` to `auto`, it will behave how I want if there's less than one row of thumbnails, but will stretch to the far left side of the viewport if there is more than one row of items.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I would venture to say that because element queries don't exist, there's not a way (at least that I know of) to do it with purely CSS. Are you opposed to using JS to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The CSS only solution (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/G7bx8/6/embedded/result/

```
div.grid {
    font-size: 170px;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 1em;
    height: 3em;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div.grid:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

div.grid > div {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #009dff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 410px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 2em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(2n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 3em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(3n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 4em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(4n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 890px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 5em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(5n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1060px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 6em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(6n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1230px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 7em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(7n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 8em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(8n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1570px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 9em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(9n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1740px) {
    div.grid {
        max-width: 10em;
    }

    div.grid > nth-child(10n) {
        clear: right;
    }
}
```

**The jQuery solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/G7bx8/7/embedded/result/

```
var size = 170;
var margin = 40;
var win = $(window);
var adjust = function() {

    $('div.grid').each(function() {

        var width = win.width() - margin;
        width = Math.floor(width / size) * size;

        $(this).width(width);
    });
};

win.resize(adjust);
adjust();
```

Comment: I seem to be able to scale your example up and the design doesn't respond.  I'd also like the size of the thumbnails to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood it in the first place, but maybe now it works as you want.

Comment: Okay, I've played with this, but it doesn't respond to having fewer than the maximum number of children needed to fill the width of the container (http://jsfiddle.net/G7bx8/2/ is an example with only two children).

Comment: That looks really good!  I will play with it and let you know how I make out.

Comment: I can't seem to get mine working exactly like yours... Want to have a look at it in-place?  CSS is here: http://www.element17.com/css/main.css.

Comment: I've adjusted it with your margins and paddings but remember, if you have msie < 9 in mind then you should use the jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/G7bx8/37/

Comment: Can you explain why it appears to be dependent on the font-size property?

Comment: It has nothing to do with font-size, I just did it that way because it's easier to handle pixel's multiples: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/5XPDm/